# Navigation drawer задвигался обратно при клике

Tags: java, android, navigation

Ребята, вот собсна в чем вопрос:
Возможно ли программно, после клика, сделать так , чтобы мой navigation drawer задвигался обратно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У класса DrawerLayout есть метод [closeDrawers()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/drawerlayout/widget/DrawerLayout#closeDrawers()).

Собственно его и нужно вызвать у вашего DrawerLayout:

```
mYourDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
```